# "The manufacturer maintained/has maintained good material quality in the past"

Tags: tense, present-perfect, past-simple

I am confused about the usage of Present Perfect and Past Simple Tense. An example:

> We are expecting normal results since the manufacturer ***maintained/has maintained*** good material quality in the past.

Which should be used here?

Answer (score 1):

You are worrying about the results *'at present'*. And, you are confident that you'll get good results. Why? Because the track/record of the maker is fine. So, go for the third possibility:

> We are expecting normal results since the manufacturer ***has been maintaining*** good material quality <del>in the past</del>.

Because in other cases, it'd be the matter of the past and you are not sure about the quality at present. The manufacturer is dealing with you at present.